# profiling fuse-python

Tags: python, profiling, signals, fuse

I am currently writing a fuse using fuse-python. It's already doing what it should. However, after it's mounted for a few weeks, it's becoming noticeably slow. So I wanted to profile it. I know about a few point where it could be optimized. But these should not be the culprits.

However, fuse-python hangs in an infinite loop (see [line 733 and 757 of the fuse source](http://fuse.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=fuse/fuse-python;a=blob;f=fuse.py;h=85fc5f067794d5cf8f52f105fff0e9c1355572dc;hb=f48986372bcfa7f6952e4d4cb442375845944810#l733)). If I run fuse in debug mode (using the `-d` switch), it will run in foreground. However, I cannot stop it with `SIGINT` nor with `CTRL+C` (which is anyway the same).

I tried to use the `signal` module to trap the signal in the main thread. But this does not work either. Interestingly, once I shoot the process down with `SIGKILL`, I see the `KeyboardInterrupt` on `stdout`. Also, after a `SIGKILL`, the signal handler is executed as expected.

This has repercussions on profiling. As the process never terminates normally, `cProfile` never gets the chance to save the stats file.

Any ideas?

Comment: @matt: I haven't had a chance to work on it yet. I've briefly read over your answer and it looks sound. I told myself I'd only accept answers that I did indeed check and verify. I'll see what I can do in the coming weeks. As it's only a very-low-priority project I do in my spare time, I don't get much time to work on it. Performance and profiling is currently the last of my concern in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python [installs a handler that raises `KeyboardInterrupt` on `SIGINT`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#module-signal). If a non-default signal handler is detected when fuse's main is called, it will [not replace the handler with its own](http://fuse.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=fuse/fuse;a=blob;f=lib/fuse_signals.c;h=88ac39e187e019b463f962533225721b089ddd19;hb=HEAD#l47), which normally calls [`fuse_session_exit`](http://fuse.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=fuse/fuse;a=blob;f=lib/fuse_signals.c;h=88ac39e187e019b463f962533225721b089ddd19;hb=HEAD#l21) and [cleans up](http://fuse.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=fuse/fuse;a=blob;f=lib/fuse_signals.c;h=88ac39e187e019b463f962533225721b089ddd19;hb=HEAD#l59). After you've called fuse's main, the [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) is swallowed by [`CFUNCTYPE`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CFUNCTYPE) wrappers and you never see them.

Your options are to:

- Send [`SIGQUIT`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, or any other terminating signal other than `SIGINT`. However fuse will not exit cleanly.
- Install the default signal handler to `SIGINT` before calling fuse's main, and restore the original when you're done.

```
old_handler =signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL)
# call main
signal(SIGINT, old_handler)
```

I'd highly recommend you switch to an alternative binding also, fuse-python is terribly messy and difficult to work with. I've had a lot of luck with [fusepy](http://code.google.com/p/fusepy/), and have submitted a few patches there.

When you're able to terminate your FUSE instance without using uncaught signals, the Python profiler will be able to save the stats as per normal.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `fusepy`. `fuse-python` is indeed terribly messy. I tried to dig into the code exactly twice. Never looked at it again ;) I will change my code to using `fusepy` first. Then I'll look up profiling again...

Comment: @exhuma: I've adapted fusepy to my own binding after some heavy use. You can read the latest version here: http://code.google.com/p/cpfs/source/browse/python/fuse.py If it's of value, I'll rip it out, document it and make a stand alone project for it.

Comment: Do you have some sort of changelog? A quick summary of the changes? I'll download it and I'll do a `diff` once I get the time. But a quick changelog would be helpful nonetheless ;)